# Are there any financial instruments that offer a set real interest rate rather than a set interest rate?

Tags: inflation, investing

Are there any financial instruments that offer a set real interest rate rather than a set interest rate? For example, an asset structured like this:

The asset is purchased at an initial price $P$ and matures after time $T$ (in years) to a value of $M$.

$M$ is defined as $P\times(1+inf)^T\times(1+r)^T$ where $inf$ is the average inflation rate between the time of purchase and maturity and $r$ is an agreed upon rate.

I am interested in this type of investment because it appears to guarantee the investor a very predictable increase in value that is independent of inflation.

Comment: do you feel that the prime rate tracks the inflation rate well, or at all? Would something that offered "prime + 2" meet your definition?

Comment: Which country's definition of inflation?

Answer (score 7):

[Treasury Inflation Protected Securities](https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/products/prod_tips_glance.htm), or TIPS, offer returns that are indexed to inflation, as measured by the Consumer Price Index.

Comment: There are also many [mutual funds](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=5119&FundIntExt=INT) that invest in these so that you don't have to figure out which particular issue(s) to buy.